# Warum ist der Apfel rot, und nicht rote?

Tags: declension, adjective-ending

Sage ich

> der rote Apfel

dann hat das Adjektiv *rot* die maskuline Endung. In vielen Sprachen würde man nun analog sagen

> Der Apfel ist rote.

sprich das Adjektiv *wird dekliniert*, auch wenn es nicht direkt am Objekt steht, doch im Deutschen nimmt man die Grundform:

> Der Apfel ist rot.

Warum steht hier die Grundform?

**Zum Vergleich:**

*Russisch*: красный (rot)

> Красное яблоко. Яблоко красное.

*Französisch*: Weil *rouge* (rot) nicht dekliniert wird, ersetze ich es durch *nouveau* (neu).

> La nouvelle pomme. La pomme est nouvelle.

(Ebenso andere lateinische Sprachen wie Italienisch, Spanisch, Portugiesisch und Rumänisch)

Comment: In anderen Sprachen wäre es "der rot Apfel" und "Der Apfel ist rot". "Rot" ist das Adjektiv in seiner 'Grundform'. In "der rote Apfel" ist das Adjektiv jedoch dekliniert. Das Deutsche passt halt die Adjektive an, damit Geschlecht, Anzahl, etc. signalisiert wird. Das Stichwort hier ist hier also Deklination.

Comment: meinst du wie in Italienisch... "Il latte/la birra e caldo/calda"? Die Frage ist garnicht so schlecht, aber vielleicht solltest du ein Beispiel aus einer anderen Sprache einfügen, so dass man versteht, worum es genau geht "Warum wird im Deutschen nur der adjektivische Gebrauch dekliniert?"

Comment: Warum gibt es einen Downvote?

Comment: @Emanuel Weil Em1 die Frage wohl nicht richtig verstanden hat und der Meinung ist, ich wüsste nicht, was Deklination ist.

Comment: Ich hab's auch erst so verstanden wie @Em1... vielleicht formulier mal wirklich etwas um. PS: Ich glaube nicht, dass der Dv von Em1 ist.

Comment: Wenn ich mich nicht vertue, haben Sprachen wie Spanisch, Russisch etc. keine separate Grundform. Im Spanischen existiert nur "rojo", "roja". Das Russische hat widerum komplette Deklination, wie das Deutsche, aber keine Grundform (es wird im Dictionary die männliche Nominativform gelistet). Interessant wäre es, wie es in anderen germanischen Sprachen aussieht. Haben die eine Grundform? Einen Vergleich mit den lateinischen oder slawischen Sprachen kann man hier schlecht ziehen. Dort ist es halt anders, weil sie eben keine Grundform haben.

Comment: @Em1 Pudels Kern: It's not a bug, it's a feature! Wie konnte ich nur übersehen, dass die anderen Sprachen das gar nicht leisten können ...

Comment: @Em1 Niederländisch is germanisch und hat Grundform: [Link](http://www.grammatiken.de/niederlaendische-grammatik-online-lernen/niederlaendische-adjektive-grundform-beugung-endung-e-uebersicht-tabelle-regeln.php)

Comment: Niederländisch und Deutsch sind schon sehr stark verwandt. Falls sich herausstellt, dass Schwedisch es anders macht, könnte man auf linguistics fragen, wie es historisch dazu kommt.

Comment: Also meine kurze Recherche sagt: Schwedisch hat eine Grundform. Schwedisch dekliniert. Schwedisch hat aber sogar unterschiedliche Deklination wenn man sagt "Die/Eine [noun] ist [adj]" und sowieso für "Die/Eine [adj] [noun]". Google Translate: Den roliga mamman. En rolig mamma. Mamman är roligt. En mamma är rolig.

Comment: @Em1... es gibt schon eine Art Grundform (meist das Maskulinum) denn der Genus ist nicht immer gegeben... Beispiel: essere stanco als Wörterbucheintrag/Google-Suche

Comment: Vielleicht solltest Du klarer machen, welche Art von Antwort Du Dir erhoffst. Ich denke, eine sinnvolle Antwort ist möglich. Da die romanischen Sprachen und die deutsche Sprache eine gemeinsame Wurzel haben, kann man fragen, wann sie sich in dieser Hinsicht auseinander entwickelt haben. Sicher kann hier jemand sagen, ob sich das Lateinische hier wie die modernen romanischen Sprachen verhält. Auch könnte hier sicher jemand sagen, wie es im Althochdeutschen aussah. Was nimmt man für die indogermanische Ursprache an?

Comment: @CarstenSchultz Ich interessiere mich nicht für die Evolution von Sprachen, sondern nur für das Deutsch, das ich von Geburt an sprechen und dessen Grammatik ich gerade deswegen nie gelernt habe. Ich habe mich gewundert, warum alle Fremdsprachen, die ich lerne, in oben genannten Punkt anders sind als das Deutsche - und Em1 hat mich ja auf die Ursache gestoßen. Insofern verstehe ich deinen Kommentar so, dass du etwas aus dieser Frage machen willst, das ich nie wollte. Und wenn dem so ist, dann mach doch, schließlich kann hier auf SX ja jeder alles editieren.

Comment: Ok, ich fand nicht, dass Em1 viel mehr geschrieben hat als dass das im Deutschen halt anders ist. Aber wenn Dir dabei etwas klarer geworden ist, ist es ja gut.

Comment: Was soll eine "maskuline Endung" sein? Der rote Apfel. Die rote Banane. Das rote Polizeiauto. "Rote" ist völlig agnostisch zum Geschlecht. Polizeiauto, Bananane und Apfel sind rot (wie jeder weiß :) ). Das -e muss an was anderem liegen - nicht dass ich wüßte woran - aber am Geschlecht liegt es nicht.

Comment: @userunknown: Banananen sind rot, aber Bananen sind meist grün, gelb oder braun (mit Grundform).

Answer (score 5):

In

> Der Apfel ist rot.

wird *rot* prädikativ verwendet (als Teil des Prädikats `rot sein`), da es den *Apfel* beschreibt. Adverbielle Verwendung ist ausgeschlossen, weil *ist* hier kein Vollverb, sondern ein Kopulaverb ist.

Die Frage, **warum** ein prädikatives Adjektiv nicht dekliniert wird (in der Grundform auftritt), ist wohl genauso schwer zu beantworten, wie die Frage, wieso mal schwache, mal starke Beugung richtig ist.

Die Mutmaßung, dass *rot*, obgleich es ein Adjektiv ist, die syntaktische Funktion eines Adverbs einnimmt, liegt nahe. Es wird also nicht dekliniert, weil dem Verb Kasus und Genus fehlen.

Wäre eine Deklination möglich, wüsste ich nicht, welche Beugung im Folgenden angebracht wäre:

> Es ist friedliche/friedliches? Er ist schnelle/schneller?

Comment: Vielen Dank. Guter Punkt!

Comment: Weder "Es ist friedliche", noch "Es ist friedliches" sind gültige Sätze. "Er ist schnelle" kenne ich auch nicht, allenfalls als veraltet für "... schnell". "Schneller" ist eine Steigerungsform - auch "Sie ist schneller".

Answer (score 4):

Das `rot` in

> der rote Apfel

ist ein attributives Adjektiv, während das `rot` in

> Der Apfel ist rot.

ein prädikativ oder adverbial gebrauchtes Adjektiv ist (siehe [syntaktische Funktion von Adjektiven](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjektiv#Syntaktische_Funktion)). Letztere Art wird, wie andere Adverbien auch, nicht flektiert (weil bereits das Verb konjugiert wurde, stelle ich jetzt mal so als Vermutung in den Raum). Bei diesem Fall bezieht sich `rot` auf das Verb `sein`. Man könnte es als die Eigenschaft `rot sein` ansehen. Deshalb ist das Genus des Subjekts nicht mehr relevant.

Comment: Verben sind konjugiert, soweit ich weiß. Ausserdem wird in Italienisch auch konjugiert und trotzdem das prädikative Adjektiv dekliniert. Die Dekliniertheit ist somit nicht zwingend mit der Behandlung des Verbs verknüpft.

Comment: @Emanuel Danke, ich hab's entsprechend geändert.

Comment: _Bei diesem Fall bezieht sich rot auf das Verb sein._ Würden wir dann nicht erwarten, dass wir danach mit "Wie ist der Apfel" oder so fragen können? (Analog zu "Wie singt er - Er singt schön"?)

Comment: @sgf Ist die Frage rein rhethorisch gemeint? "Wie ist der Apfel? - Er ist rot." klingt für mich in Ordnung

Comment: @Harald Nein, für mich klingt das tatsächlich komisch, ich hatte sogar gedacht, dass das für jeden so ist.

Answer (score 0):

Die Frage, warum in dieser einen Sprache diese eine spezielle Regel gilt, in einer anderen aber nicht, ist müßig. Die ebenso wahre wie unbefriedigende Antwort ist:

- Weil es verschiedene Sprachen sind.

---

Das Argument, dass verwandte Sprachen ja eigentlich auch gleiche oder ähnliche Regeln haben müssten, ist natürlich ein sehr gutes. Je enger zwei Sprachen miteinander verwandt sind, desto mehr gleiche Regeln gibt es.

Aber es gibt auch immer Regeln, die unterschiedlich sind. Denn wären alle Regeln gleich, dann gebe es überhaupt keinen Unterschied mehr. Die beiden Sprachen wären dann identisch. (Dabei zähle ich zu den Regeln nicht nur die Grammatik und die Ausspracheregeln, sondern auch das Vokabular, denn auch das sind letztendlich Regeln, nämlich Regeln, die Lautfolgen auf Bedeutungen abbilden.)

Mit anderen Worten: Wenn zwei Sprachen unterschiedlich sind, muss sich der Unterschied ja irgendwo manifestieren. Daher muss es zwingend Regeln geben, die voneinander abweichen.

Welche Regeln das im konkreten Fall sind, ist ein Ergebnis des Zufalls.

---

**Zusatz**
(Der folgende Teil ist nicht mehr als Teil der Antwort gedacht)

Wie kommt es denn überhaupt dazu, dass es unterschiedliche Sprachen gibt?

In Europa ist es so, dass einige der hier gesprochenen Sprachen von den uralischen Sprachen abstammen (Finnish, Ungarisch), die anderen von den indoeuropäischen Sprachen, darunter die Westgermanischen Sprachen, zu denen unter anderem Deutsch und Englisch gehören.

Es deutet einiges darauf hin, dass vor ca. dem 6. Jahrhundert in Europa eine gemeinsame ur-westgermanische Sprache gesprochen wurde, und zwar in einem breiten Streifen von Norditalien bis zur Nordsee, einschließlich der Ostküste Großbritanniens. Der Osten des heutigen Österreichs gehörte nicht dazu, ebensowenig das Gebiet auf dem eine Zeit lang die DDR existierte, dafür aber das Gebiet der heutigen Benelux-Länder und der Nordosten Frankreichs.

Diese urwestgermanische Sprache wurde in vielen verschiedenen Dialekten gesprochen. Sie war also vielmehr ein Kontinuum vieler ähnlicher Dialekte, die sich gegenseitig beeinflussten. Ohne eine Fremdsprache zu lernen, konnte jeder mit allen Leuten reden, die nur ein oder zwei Tagesreises entfernt waren, denn die lokalen Dialekte gingen fließend in die Dialekte der Nachbarregionen über. Aber jemand, der in der italienischen Po-Ebene gelebt hat, dürfte erhebliche Probleme gehabt haben, jemanden zu verstehen, der an der britischen Ostküste lebte.

Für die deutschen Dialekte gilt das auch heute noch. Jeder, der aus dem Norden Deutschlands stammt und Urlaub in Österreich oder der Schweiz gemacht hat, kann das bestätigen.

Im Lauf der Zeit haben einige Leute in einer bestimmten Region ohne besonderen Grund angefangen, bestimmte Wörter anderes auszusprechen oder sie haben Grammatikregeln geringfügig abgeändert (das passiert auch heute noch und ist ein unbewusster Prozess). Wenn das die anderen Bewohner des Dorfes nachgemacht haben, und sich diese neue Mode in die Nachbardörfer verbreitet hat, hat das den lokalen Dialekt verändert.

20 km weiter hat sich vielleicht eine andere lokale Variation entwickelt. Das kann dann entweder dazu geführt haben, dass sich einzelne dieser Variationen auch in größeren Regionen durchgesetzt haben, oder dass sie wieder verschwunden sind. Es ist aber auch passiert, dass in Region A und Region B der Unterschied weiterbestanden hat, und dass er sich im Lauf der Zeit verstärkt hat. Das passierte besonders häufig dann, wenn geographische oder politische Gründe die Kommunikation zwischen diesen Regionen behinderten.

Irgendwann konnte man dann nicht mehr von einem Kontinuum sprechen. Um das Jahr 600 herum gab es Altenglisch auf Großbritannien, Althochdeutsch im Alpenraum, und  dazwischen Altfriesisch, Altsächsisch, Altniederländisch und Altmittelfränkisch. Das Althochdeutsch konnte man noch weiter untergliedern in Langobardisch (in Oberitalien), Altbayrisch (Bayern und Teile des heutigen Österreich), Altalemannisch (heutige Schweiz, Schwabenland), Altostfränkisch und Altthüringisch.

Diese Sprachen gelten als unterschiedlich, aber doch noch als so eng verwandt miteinander, dass eine Kommunikation ohne Dolmetscher auch mit Sprechern benachbarter Sprachen möglich war.

Innerhalb der Regionen näherten sich die lokalen Dialekte aneinander an, dafür wuchsen die Unterschiede zwischen den Sprachen, und heute gelingt es einem deutschen Muttersprachler kaum noch eine Unterhaltung in niederländischer Sprache zu verstehen, und der Unterschied zwischen Deutsch und Englisch ist sogar noch größer.

Answer (score -6):

> Der Apfel ist rot.

Allgemeine Regel: In prädikativer Position (z. B. nach dem Verb *sein*) hat das Adjektiv im Deutschen generell keine Endung.

Warum? Vielleicht deswegen, weil das Deutsche beim attributiven Adjektiv ein so aufwendiges Deklinationssystem hat, verwendet man bei prädikativem Gebrauch nur die Kurzform. Aber das ist wirklich nur eine Hypothese. Es würde aufwendige linguistische Forschung erfordern, wenn man hier einen Grund finden wollte. Und wahrscheinlich käme dabei nichts Konkretes heraus.

Comment: Die Regel ist: Wenn prädikativ gebraucht, hat das Adjektiv keine Endung.

Comment: Das ist schon klare(s), mich stört lediglich das "kann"... als ob man sich dazu entscheiden könnte, *die* (welche denn?) Endung dranzulassen. Außerdem: Warum kann man die darauffolgende Argumentation nicht für attributive Adjektive heranziehen? Z.B.: Die ewig Liebe? Ein stumm Mann? Das entzückt Kind?

Comment: Die Deklination der Adjektive ist fÜr Lernende etwas schwierig.

Comment: Das erklärt jede Grunggrammatik.

Comment: Deine Argumentation ist stark anzweifelbar. Wie @Grantwalzer schon sagt: Wenn bei der prädikativen Verwendung wegen dem vorhanden Artikel die Endung wegfallen darf, warum dann nich auch bei der attributiven Verwendung? Das widerspricht hier jeder Logik.

Comment: Die Frage von OP war nicht WIE es ist, sondern WARUM das so ist. Kommt leider nicht so ganz raus, wird aber in den Kommentaren geklärt.

Comment: Ich habe meine Formulierung so geändert, dass hoffentlich keine Einwände mehr kommen.

Comment: Schon besser. Hab meinen DV zurückgezogen.