# »wenn ich mich nicht vertue« – origin of »vertue«

Tags: etymology

In another thread, user Em1 begins a [comment](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/15547/warum-ist-der-apfel-rot-und-nicht-rote#comment37119_15547) with the phrase,

> wenn ich mich nicht vertue ...

which I understand as

> if I’m not mistaken ...

What is that verb he’s using? It looks to me like it comes from the Yiddish noun *tuos* (mistake), which in turn is from the Hebrew. Am I correct about this?

Comment: The http://www.yiddishdictionaryonline.com/ translate "mistake" as "toes" not "tous", and English "do" as "ton". Do you agree with that? It wouldn't really change my answer, except that I maybe would quote a further part from Grimm: "nebenformen im 15. jahrh. tôn toen"

Comment: Yes, "toes" is the standard transcription, based on the northern or "Litvak" prononciation. In our Polish-Galician tradition it would have been closer to "tuos". Either way, it's definitely from the Hebrew...nothing to do with "tun". The Yiddish "ton" (to do) comes from the German without a doubt.

Comment: By the way, the phrase "wenn ich mich nicht *irre*" is much more common.

Comment: @RomanReiner Agree, but only in this context. *Vertun* is more apt for practical contexts. For example: when someone made a mistake while making a knot, *er hat sich vertan* seems more appropriate.

Answer (score 8):

The letters *ver* should always ring the compound bell. Also, the prefix gives more insight into the meaning than the straightforward *tun* (to do):

Among quite a few functions,

> ver-

can express that something is done wrong. A few examples:

> verrechnen (calculate incorrectly, to miscalculate)
>   verschießen (to waste a shot)
>   verfehlen (to miss (a target))
>   verspielen (to gamble away, to squander)

So in combination with *tun*, it basically means doing something the wrong way (to misdo).
In everyday use, it often goes in the direction of *misuse, misplace*.

**Finally,**

when it's used together with a reflexive pronoun, it means *to make a mistake, to err*.
In Em1's context, it could be paraphrased as *"if I'm not making a mistake in the process of remembering/thinking"* or *"if I'm not typing/telling you something wrong"*.
Note that in the cited context, *sich irren* is more common. Probably because *sich vertun* has a strong practical connotation.

---

**As to the Yiddish aspect:**

1. According to Duden, *vertun* already existed in Old High German in the form of *fertuon*. That goes hand in hand with the relation of *tun* and *tuon*.
2. If it's that old indeed, than it's older than Yiddish.
3. So one would have to argue that it derives from the Hebrew טעות (taut?, tayt?, tavt?), and that *ver-* has the positive, attributing, final meanging here, of making sth. into sth., but that seems a rather weak alternative.

Answer (score 7):

The Verb he is using is *vertun.*

There are two meanings:

1. *Etwas (Wertvolles, Unwiderbringliches o. Ä.) nutzlos, mit nichtigen Dingen verschwenden, vergeuden.* (to waste something valuable; no reason)

   coming from Middle High German: *vertuon*
   or Old High German: *fertuon*

   Examples:

   - Zeit, Geld nutzlos vertun (waste time, money)
   - eine Chance vertun (missing an opportunity)
2. *sich (bei etwas) irren, einen Fehler machen (make a mistake, to be wrong)*

   Grammar: *sich vertun*

   It is a colloquialism.

   Examples:

   - sich beim Rechnen, Eintippen vertun (to mispurchase)

You can always look up German words (spelling, meaning, etymology) in [the Duden online dictionary](http://duden.de).