# Adjective declension

Tags: grammar, adjective, declension

I am confused about adjective endings and placement.

Example:

> (1) Mein alter Pullover ist sehr hässlich.
>
> (2) Mein hässlicher Pullover ist sehr alt.
>
> (3) Mein Pullover ist sehr alt und hässlich.

My question is this: In all three cases the pullover is both old and ugly, yet why is it that depending on where the adjectives are they either take the *-er* ending (since it is *der Pullover*) or not?

In other words, why is it not:

> Mein alter Pullover ist sehr hässlicher.

Comment: You have to study adjective declensions in German. https://deutsch.lingolia.com/de/grammatik/adjektive/deklination

Comment: This has already been thoroughly discussed in http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/22117/why-ein-blaues-hemd-and-not-ein-blau-hemd and http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/13765/deutscher-schäferhund-or-deutsche-schäferhund. Please start a survey of existing posts using tags and search function before producing duplicates, it makes topics much easier to handle.

Comment: This question is nearer to http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/15547/warum-ist-der-apfel-rot-und-nicht-rote?lq=1 than to those mentioned as duplicates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The adjectives *alt* and *hässlich* in your last sentence, (3), are predicative. So is the second adjective in (1) and (2). Predicative are not declined; they occur after the verb *sein* there. In these three sentences you wrote the declension (and the absence thereof) correctly.

Regarding the question pertaining the last sentence: it's wrong because the adjective *hässlich* appears there qualifying your noun, *Pullover*, via a verbal construction; it doesn't need an ending. You don't need to decline those. Decline those adjectives directly qualifying the noun (*attributive adjectives*), as you correctly did with *alter*.

Comment: Thanks. Although, as a learner it is still quite confusing. I guess I don't know enough about declination. To me the Pullover in all three is old and ugly and should have the same endings regardless of position? That would be too easy though :)

Comment: It's not about position, it's about function.

Comment: When you learn a foreign language you should not suppose that the foreign grammarr is as in English. Things can be done very differently and that is why you should work with a grammar where things that are different from English are explained.